# Ruby Koans: test_sometimes_missing_parentheses_are_ambiguous

Tags: ruby

I am completing Neo's Ruby Koans (http://rubykoans.com/). In about_methods.rb, the koan instructs to correct the following, currently broken, eval:

```
# (NOTE: We are Using eval below because the example code is
  # considered to be syntactically invalid).
  def test_sometimes_missing_parentheses_are_ambiguous
    eval "assert_equal (5), my_global_method (2, 3)" # ENABLE CHECK
    #
    # Ruby doesn't know if you mean:
    #
    #   assert_equal(5, my_global_method(2), 3)
    # or
    #   assert_equal(5, my_global_method(2, 3))
    #
    # Rewrite the eval string to continue.
    #
 end
```

my_global_method is

```
def my_global_method(a,b)
  a + b
end
```

How do I need to alter the eval to pass this test?

Edit: [RubyKoans: broken koan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102506/rubykoans-broken-koan) asked whether this code was broken or not, and while it indicates that the question is working as intended, no answer to the koan is supplied.

The error is as follows:

```
(eval):1: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('    (SyntaxError)
assert_equal 5, my_global_method 2, 3
```

Comment: the problem is the parenthesis around `(5)`. ruby thinks you are calling `assert_equal(5)` with just one argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to:

```
eval "assert_equal 5, my_global_method(2, 3)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You want your eval line to look something more like this:

> eval "assert_equal 5, my_global_method(2, 3)" # ENABLE CHECK

Your error is telling you that it can't understand the parameters being passed to it, as it is missing parentheses. They put that code in incorrectly to demonstrate the need for parentheses when calling a method with several parameters.